# How can I prove that $a_n \le 2$ with induction for given progression?

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

When given progression is: $$ {a_n}_{+1} = \frac{(a_n)^2}{4}  + 1$$   $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a_1 = 0$

Comment: I actually have no idea how to start this. 
Typically I would start with n = 1, look if equation is equal and then go for induction step with n+1.
But in this case I don't know what to do.

Comment: Suppose that $a_n\le 2$, then $(a_n)^2/4\le 1$.

Comment: @Masacroso How do you get to the point that $ \frac {(a_n)^2}{4} \le 1$?

Comment: Because if $0\le a_n\le 2$, and because the function $f(x)=x^2$ is strictly increasing for $x>0$, this mean that the maximum, when $0\le a_n\le 2$, is achieved when $a_n=2$. The characteristics of the functions $x^a$ can be proved from the axioms of the ordered field $\Bbb R$.

Comment: I had a mistake in my first comment: to conclude that $(a_n)^2/4\le 1$ we must suppose first that $0\le a_n\le 2$ and not only that $a_n\le 2$. Sorry.

Comment: Is it right that we can suppose $0 \le a_n \le 2$ because of  $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: I dont know what you mean when you says "because of $\Bbb N$". You can take as hypothesis that $0\le a_n\le 2$, because the base step hold it. Now from this hypothesis you can prove that, effectively, $0\le a_n\le 2$ what implies that $a_n\le 2$.

Comment: @Masacroso Thank you, I think I got it now. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

For the step $n+1$ (assuming that $a_n \le 2$)

$$a_{n+1}=\frac{(a_n)^2}{4}+1\le \frac{(2)^2}{4}+1=2$$

Now you just have to show that is valid for $n=1$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! 
So can I say that with given $a_n = 0$ the induction is proven?

Comment: @Andreas: right!

Comment: Thank you very much. This helps a lot. (Even if it shouldn't be that hard to solve, I guess).

Comment: Just remember those three steps: 1) prove for $n=1$; 2) suppose that it is valid for $n$; 3) using $(2)$ show that is also valid for $n+1$

Comment: I got the general idea of the induction, however my problem in this case was to work with $a_n$ and ${a_n}_{+1}$.

Comment: I see. That is the main issue, but after some pratice it will not be a problem any more.

Comment: Ok, I hope so. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{array} {rl}
\text{Assumption} & a_n \in [0 ~ .. 2] \\
\text{Therefore} &  a_n{}^2 \in [? ~ .. ?] \\
\text{Therefore} &  \frac 14 a_n{}^2 + 1 \in [? ~ .. ?] \\
\text{Therefore} &  a_{n + 1} \in [? ~ .. ?] \\
\end{array}$$

Figure out the $?$.

Comment: Is it true for $(a_n)^2 \in [0 ... 4]$?

Comment: Probably I don't get it.

Comment: @Andreas yes, it is true that if $a_n \in [0 ~.. ~2]$ then $a_n{}^2 \in [0 ~ .. ~ 4]$

Comment: Alright, then $\frac{(a_n)^2}{4}+1 \in [0..2]$. 
Is that true and what does it say about ${a_n}_{+1}$?

Comment: @Andreas That is true, and for what it says about $a_{n+1}$, remember that $a_{n+1} = \frac 14 a_n{}^2 + 1$

Comment: Great, thank you. Did not get that on the first view. You helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Is $a_1 \le 2$? If $a_n \le 2$, is it true that $a_{n+1} \le 2$? What's $2^2$? What's $1+1$?

Comment: * Yes, $a_1 = 1 \le 2$
* I don't know if ${a_n}_{+1} \le 2$

Comment: @Andreas Unit's point is that you can deduce whether $a_{n+1}\leq 2$ based on whether $a_n$ is. Consider this: $a_{n+1}$ increases monotonically with $a_n$, that is the greater the value of $a_n$, the greater the value of $a_{n+1}$ (if we had negative values, this wouldn't be true, but we clearly don't). So if $a_n\leq 2$, then for all possible values of $a_{n+1}$, the greatest occurs if $a_n=2$. If $a_n<2$, then $a_{n+1}$ is less than that greatest value. What is that greatest value?